Scheduling notifications for android and iOS in flutter
I am developing a flutter calender/todo-app where it should be possible to add notifications to your events/todos. Like one-time notifications and also repeating notifications for repeating tasks like going shopping or birthdays.
I decided to use the flutter_local_notifications package for that and everytime I come up with an idea how to implement it Apple comes in with some restrictions.
Scheduling all notifications on creation of an event/todo is not an option, because iOS has a limit of 64 scheduled notifications
Also, how would I implement repeating events like a birthday? I can't just schedule 100 years in advance
So I tought I could run a background process every day at 0:00 that schedules all notifications for the current day. I looked into cron, background_fetch and now into workmanager.
But as far as I understand, iOS does not support running a background task at a specific time (0:00) and also will stop running the background process after the user did not use my app for "a long time".
I am confused and actually have no idea anymore. How are other devs solving this issue? Am I missunderstanding the restrictions? Am I missing something?
I am happy for EVERY help!
